# Why am I notified about some missed calls via a text from +8888?

Tags: ios, iphone, call

Most of the time when there's a missed call, it shows up when I go to Phone app->Recents. Sometimes I get a text from Rogers (+8888) telling me the number and when they called. When that happens, it doesn't show up in the Phone app.

I've got an iPhone 4, iOS 7, although this has been happening for longer than I've had iOS 7.

Answer (score 2):

5 seconds with google showed me this: http://forums.crackberry.com/blackberry-pearl-flip-f85/rogers-sends-8888-text-message-every-time-someone-calls-332862/

Seems to be a "service" Rogers offers where they notify you if you miss a call. You need to call their customer support line and ask them to disable the "Whocalled" service on your contract.

Comment: It doesn't send me the Whocalled message every time though, only some of the time.

Comment: Could simply be a service issue with Rogers where it is intermittent.

Comment: If your phone actually rings and gets the missed call, there is no text sent.  The text is sent if the phone is off or has no signal.